# Closing Macbook lid changes external screen to primary

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

I've recently got a new Macbook with Big Sur and I'm observing some different behaviour compared to my old Macbook with Catalina.

I have an external monitor connected as a secondary display and I have a video player streaming on full-screen on it. When I close the lid, on Catalina my video keeps playing on the external secondary display, however on my new laptop when I close the lid the external display turns into primary, and I'm seeing my laptop's windows rather than the video.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: What player are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Again, another stab at the dark here:
Either:
(Easy route) remove the monitor's cable from the computer/ or manually put it to sleep OR
open up your terminal and write the command
'pmset -g'

it will display your current power management settings.

from then on you could try disabling lidwake, acwake or messing around with the gpu switch option(though, honestly i think its only related to either enforcing dedicated or external/separate internal gpu settings ).

Also, try disabling the darkwake option.(which is not listed within pmset's man pages but you can google your way thru understanding it)
pmset -c darkwake 0

- Note: all pmset values require sudo access

Answer (score 0):

This is, somewhat, by design - you are able to use your laptop as a computer completely independently of its own peripherals; just as you would with a Mac Mini, by simply closing the lid.

The simple answer is to unplug your laptop from the wall outlet, which disables this mode.

See below:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834